# Dynamically creating object instance of interface / abstract class

Tags: java, groovy, abstract-class

In Groovy or Java, assume I have an interface (or abstract class) with some unimplemented methods.  I would like to generate an instance of this interface/abstract class *dynamically in runtime*, and have some behaviour for those unimplemented methods (e.g. based on annotation on those methods)

i.e. something like

```java
interface Foo {
    @SomeAnnotation(...)
    foo();
}
```

```java
Foo foo = someMagic(Foo.class, somethingToProvideLogicOfUnimplementedMethods);
```

Are there any library or technique that can achieve this?

Comment: I kinda remember cglib and javassist may be able to achieve similar thing, but I want to see if it is the correct direction to go before I dig into them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Groovy the following magic is called *"Map to Interface coercion"* and is available out of the box:

```
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME
import java.lang.annotation.Retention
import java.lang.annotation.Target

@Retention( RUNTIME )
@Target( [ METHOD ] )
@interface Some {
  String value() default ''
}

interface Foo {
  @Some( 'AWESOME' )
  void foo()
}

Foo magicFoo = [ foo:{->
  String annotationValue = Foo.methods.first().annotations.first().value()
  println "the $annotationValue MAGIC printed!"
} ] as Foo

assert Foo.isAssignableFrom( magicFoo.getClass() )

magicFoo.foo()
```

prints in the console:

```
the AWESOME MAGIC printed!
```

Comment: I added the annotation connection into the code

Comment: Cool trick and easy enough to do! Thanks for guiding me to this